# Nginx rewrite urls to match proxy address

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I am running a wordpress docker container, the site is accessible through host machines port `8000`, if go to localhost:8000 boom I get to see my wordpress site.

It's boring to always type `localhost:8000` to see my website, so I decided to commission nginx as a reverse proxy for my site. I've set up a virtual host in nginx that has the name `proxy.site`, I can now access by wordpress site by visiting `http://proxy.site`.

Up until this point, we are doing great, when `http://proxy.site` opens up, I can see a list of my blog posts, lets say I want to read my latest blog post about COVID-19, when I click on the link, ohohohoho it opens up as `http://localhost:8000/posts/covid19`

I want it to open with the proxy url as in `http://proxy.site/posts/covid19`, I need to whole site to be accessible through the `http://proxy.site` site name,

I need nginx to rewrite all my links in `localhost:8000/*` to `proxy.site/*`, nobody loves typing ports when accessing a blog,

Here is how my nginx conf file looks like

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/proxy.site/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name proxy.site www.proxy.site;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                #proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                #proxy_redirect http://localhost:8000/ http://proxy.site/ ;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

How do i achieve rewrite all urls in the proxied site with my custom host name?

Comment: Actually, you need to configure your wordpress generate right links. https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Comment: thsi won't work. I've tried it.

Comment: You should find out what you did wrong. At least add `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

Comment: This forces the client's request to be rewritten to mach the proxied address.  Its not ideal to use this as well.